# QObject signals and slots not accessing function

Tags: c++, qt

I have a function which I am trying to connect via signals and slots but the function isn't being called when I run the executable file. I have put a debug error in my function so I know it isn't being called. My code is shown below:

My header file:

```
#include "MyWidget.h"
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

class MyClass: public QObject{

    Q_OBJECT
    public:
    MyClass( QObject *parent = nullptr);
    MyWidget *myWidget;

    public slots:
    void setTranslation(int value);
};

#endif
```

My source file:

```
#include "MyClass.h"

MyClass::MyClass(QObject *parent): QObject(parent)
{
    some code here....

    QSlider *xSlider = new QSlider(Qt::Vertical);
    xSlider->setRange(0, 10);

    QObject::connect(xSlider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
                 this, SLOT(setTranslation(int)));

    some code here...
}

void MyClass::setTranslation(int value)
{
    some code here...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add the `Q_OBJECT` macro immediately after the class declaration. It is what the MOC (Meta Object Compiler) uses to generate additional meta information for your code.

```
class MyClass: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    // all other class data, member function declaration

public:
    MyClass( QObject *parent = nullptr );
};
```

This should be good enough.

---

**EDIT:**

Also remember to take a `nullptr` defaulted `QObject` pointer in your default constructor.

Comment: Even after adding Q_OBJECT into my file it still comes up with the same error but now it says:

QObject::connect: No such slot MyClass::setTranslation(int value) instead

Comment: Please see my edit and perhaps you need to rebuild your code.

Comment: @Jade You need to insert `Q_OBJECT` at the very top of your class definition. All of your other lines remain the same. btw, here's the relevant documention: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html#a-small-example

Comment: I have included both of what you have suggested and deleted my .o files and exe file and rebuilt the project and even though it compiles fine when I open the file it still can't find the setTranslation function

Comment: @Jade hrm, maybe try explicitly re-running qmake between cleaning the project and rebuilding. its possible the `moc` stuff isn't getting regenerated. otherwise I'm at a loss - Josh has the right answer. A missing Q_OBJECT macro will cause signals/slots to fail (and you were definitely missing the macro).

Comment: Yeah I've tried doing the qmake again but still no luck!:/

Comment: I've deleted the moc files too and rebuilt they do regenerate so I'm at a loss.

Comment: @Josh I've now not got any error, but my function isn't being accessed, I know this as I've got a debug error in my function which isn't printing to the console. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you explicitly set the value of *xSlider* via QSlider::setValue( int) to a valid digit within the range( 0, 10 )? If yes, can you post a sample code of your slot, maybe in the comment box here using pastebin?

Comment: With a little bit of moving things around I've managed to get it working:)